# resolve Non-exist Domain Name to local IP using dnsmasq

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, openwrt, dnsmasq

When user inquiries a Non-exist domain name (e.g. http://www.not-exist-website.com/), is it possible to resolve it to a local IP using dnsmasq?

Another situation, when dnsmasq cannot resolve the request domain name (e.g. http://www.google.com/ in China) is it possible to resolve it to a local IP using dnsmasq?

PS:

I don't know if there are differences with the above situations in implementation.

I am developing OpenWRT routers with dnsmasq as local DNS server.

Local IP runs a nginx server hosting a local homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Add to /etc/hosts

```
192.168.0.10 www.nonexistentdomain.com www
```

Add the following to /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
domain=nonexistentdomain.com
```

You can make dnsmasq authoritative for a given domain by adding the following line

```
domain=existingdomain.com
```

Please note that the dns resolution for above domain is restricted to local entries.

You can add entries for existing domain into /etc/hosts

```
192.168.1.10 www.existingdomain.com
```